# Нет перевода текста на странице поиска по метке/ам при отсутствии вопросов по ней/ним

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки, поиск

[ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоже самое, если [>1 метки в поиске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12116

   Предложил:

   > Нет вопросов с меткой [$tagname$]. Посмотрите список доступных меток для этого сайта.
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12115

   Предложил:

   > Нет вопросов с любой из следующих меток: [$tagnames$]. Посмотрите список доступных меток для этого сайта.

Comment: Убрал скобки и утвердил. Скобки не нужны, т.к. метка отображается не голым текстом.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хм, а почему тогда сейчас со скобками [tag:ошибка]? о_О

Comment: потому что кто-то два раза утвердил :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ (¬‿¬ )